# Symfony error on persisting object

Tags: php, sql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im trying to make a simple form with subforms on symfony. My problem is that when I persist and object on the controller

```
$em->persist($professional);
foreach($form['degrees'] as $key){
  $degree = new ProfessionalDegree();
  $degree->setTitle($key['title']->getData());
  $degree->setPlace($key['place']->getData());
  $degree->setDateIn(new \DateTime($key['date_in']->getData()->format('Y-m-d')));
  $degree->setDateOut(new \DateTime($key['date_out']->getData()->format('Y-m-d')));
  $degree->setProfessional($professional);

  $em->persist($degree);
}
$em->flush()
```

The database does add two fields, one with the professional on NULL and the other one with the good relation:

[image]

//UPDATED //

```
Here is the ProfessionalExperience entity

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="professional_experience")
 */
class ProfessionalExperience
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }     

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     *
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     *
     */
    private $date_in;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     *
     */
    private $date_out;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     *
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Professional", inversedBy="experiences", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="professional_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $professional;

...
```

And here is my Professional entity

```
class Professional extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->followers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->following = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

...

/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProfessionalDegree", mappedBy="professional", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $degrees;
```

// EDITED 2 //

There is my form:

```
    protected function editProfileFormProfessional($professional, $request) {

            $form = $this->createForm(ProfessionalType::class, $professional, [
            ... 
            $form->add('degrees', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'   => DegreeType::class,
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ));
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {

            if($form->isValid()){

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $professional->setName($form['name']->getData());
                $professional->setSurName($form['surname']->getData());
                $professional->setProfession($form['profession']->getData());
                $professional->setCountry($form['country']->getData());
                $professional->setProvince($form['province']->getData());
                $professional->setCity($form['city']->getData());
                $professional->setZipCode($form['zip_code']->getData());
                $professional->setBirthPlace($form['birth_place']->getData());
                $professional->setRefereeNumber($form['referee_number']->getData());
                $professional->setRefereePlace($form['referee_place']->getData());
                $professional->setAboutMe($form['about_me']->getData());

                $em->persist($professional);
                $em->flush();

             foreach($form['degrees'] as $key){
                $degree = new ProfessionalDegree();
                $degree->setTitle($key['title']->getData());
                $degree->setPlace($key['place']->getData());
                $degree->setDateIn(new \DateTime($key['date_in']->getData()->format('Y-m-d')));
                $degree->setDateOut(new \DateTime($key['date_out']->getData()->format('Y-m-d')));
                $degree->setProfessional($professional);

                $em->persist($degree);
               }
             $em->flush();
```

Note that the PorfesionalDegree has cascade all because if i don't add these I have the persist cascade error.

// EDITED 3

Now i know where the mistake is, on calling the handle request before all the sets, it adds the field by his own.
But the problem is that the professional is still NULL, i've modify my form, by adding this:

```
->add('degrees', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => DegreeType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ));
```

With by_reference on false, it should just do it, but still setting the professional at NULL. I've followed what Symfony says on its guide:

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

But still nothing

Does anyone know why?
Thank you

Comment: You'd have to post the entity class files probably.

Comment: and the form would be great too

Comment: At least `$form` contents, so we know your your input. The model and the database structure as well. And where does `$professional` come from? is it persisted correctly?

Comment: Flush professional before the foreach, maybe it is because professional does not have an id yet(you need to be saved to have an id)

Comment: @Erik there are my entities

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi already tried, nothing.

Comment: flush professional then use dump on it and check that it has an id? (desperate measures but lets be thorough :P )

Comment: @yivi added the form

Comment: @JoeYahchouchi Yes, it has id, the point is that it saves 2 values, one correct and the other wrong like the img

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to flush before your foreach loop.

To debug properly you can watch what happen in your loop like that :

```
foreach($form['degrees'] as $key){
            $degree = new ProfessionalDegree();
            $degree->setTitle($key['title']->getData());
            $degree->setPlace($key['place']->getData());
            $degree->setDateIn(new \DateTime($key['date_in']->getData()->format('Y-m-d')));
            $degree->setDateOut(new \DateTime($key['date_out']->getData()->format('Y-m-d')));
            $degree->setProfessional($professional);

            var_dump($degree->getId());
            var_dump($degree->getProfessional());

            $em->persist($degree);
           }

die();
```

Here you'll understand better what happened and debug as you need.

And please, don't set your $professional object like that. Use :

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

And Finaly use a FormType : http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

Good luck :)

Comment: Thank u it helped to much, now i know where the mistake is, I added a new update to my code

Comment: I reopened a new question for making it easy to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716039/symfony-by-reference-not-working