# Symfony by_reference not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Im trying to create a simple OneToMany association with 2 entities:

```
class Professional extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->followers = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->following = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->degrees = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->experiences = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
...
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProfessionalDegree", mappedBy="professional", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $degrees;
...
**
     * Add degrees
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalDegrees $degrees
     * @return Professional
     */
    public function addDegree(\AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalDegree $degrees)
    {
        $this->degrees[] = $degrees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove degrees
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalDegrees $degrees
     */
    public function removeDegree(\AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalDegree $degrees)
    {
        $this->degrees->removeElement($degrees);
    }

    /**
     * Get degrees
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDegrees()
    {
        return $this->degrees;
    }
```

And

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="professional_degree")
 */
class ProfessionalDegree
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
...

/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Professional", inversedBy="degrees")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="professional_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $professional;

...

/**
     * Set professional
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Professional $professional
     * @return ProfessionalDegree
     */
    public function setProfessional(\AppBundle\Entity\Professional $professional = null)
    {
        $this->professional = $professional;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get professional
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Professional 
     */
    public function getProfessional()
    {
        return $this->professional;
    }
```

When im trying to create the form using the Type:

```
class ProfessionalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    { 
     $builder
        ->add($builder->create('degrees', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type'   => DegreeType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        )));
    }

    public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'professional_registration_form';
}

public function getName()
{
    return $this->getBlockPrefix();
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => array('ProfessionalRegistration'),
        ));
}
}
```

With these DegreeType:

```
class DegreeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {  
        $builder
        ->add('title')
        ->add('place')
        ->add('date_in', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text'
            ))
        ->add('date_out', DateType::class, array(
            'widget' => 'single_text'
            ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'degree_registration_form';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ProfessionalDegree::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

When i handle the form on the controller, the new degree is added to the database but with the professional at NULL. I've read in Symfony's doc (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) that it might be a 'by_reference' problem

Any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: By setting `by_reference` to false you are already forcing the setter to be called so this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Nothing seems to be wrong with your form types either.

Maybe you should try adding cascade persist to the many-to-one annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest you to do is to manually call the ProfessionalDegrees setProfessional method when calling addDegree on Professional:

```
/**
 * Add degrees
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalDegrees $degrees
 * @return Professional
 */
public function addDegree(\AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalDegree $degrees)
{
    $degrees->setProfessional($this);
    $this->degrees[] = $degrees;

    return $this;
}
```

You should also use cascade_validation in your form so degrees you add through the Professional will also be validated